# NHibernate Proxy Id Value

Tags: nhibernate

Seeing a scenario where upon loading an entity by id, NH is loading via proxy (which is expected), however, backing fields for id = 0, but virtual property (getter), is the id of the entity from the db.

Example:

```
private int _id;
public virtual int Id { get { return _id; } }
```

and mapping

```
...
<id name="Id" access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore">
...
```

Upon loading the entity, the _id = 0, but Id = 4 for example.

Is it normal behaviour for the backing fields to not be initialised while entity is proxied?

Comment: Should of mentioned, on NH 3.3.3 latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say: do not worry. There is nothing wrong. And it is *normal behaviour*.

You can try to create another property, e.g.

```
public virtual int MyTestId 
{ 
   get { return _id + 1; }
}
```

And you'll see that `MyTestId` is 5 *(to continue the case study above, when the Id == 4)*. Simply, you've most likely faced the VS debugger... which is just a human.